# MySql Query in Python LIKE with Wildcard

Tags: python, mysql, wildcard, sql-like

I have seen this question around but the answer that is usually given, does not work with me.
I am trying to do a simple query

```
query_pre_company = "SELECT `name` FROM `seta`.`companies` WHERE `companies`.`name` LIKE SOUNDEX(%s) OR(`companies`.`name` LIKE %s)"
name = sheet.cell(2,2).value #from an excel sheet
name_check='%'+name+'%'
rows_count=cursor.execute(query_pre_company,[name_check])
```

the result is the error

````
  ```query = query % tuple([db.literal(item) for item in args])
  TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting```
````

I also tried

`rows_count=cursor.execute(query_pre_company,(name_check,))`

and a million of other different variations including sticking '%%s%' directly in the query and others

Please help
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have two placeholders, you need to pass two parameters. The parameter for `SOUNDEX()` should be the name without the wildcards added.

You're also not using `SOUNDEX()` correctly. It doesn't return a `lIKE` pattern, it returns a code string. You need to call it on the column as well and compare them.

```
query_pre_company = """SELECT `name` 
                    FROM `seta`.`companies` 
                    WHERE SOUNDEX(`companies`.`name`) = SOUNDEX(%s) 
                    OR `companies`.`name` LIKE %s"""
name = sheet.cell(2,2).value #from an excel sheet
name_check='%'+name+'%'
rows_count=cursor.execute(query_pre_company,[name, name_check])
```